# How to catch “Access denied” using plink from powershell script

Tags: powershell, plink

I have a powershell script that calls the following command:

`plink -batch -ssh $defUser@$srv -pw $defPassword -m $executeCommandFile`

The problem that $defPassword is not always the same/correct. How can I catch Access denied error from plink?

Something like this:

```
if (plink -batch -ssh $defUser@$srv -pw $defPassword -ne "Access denied") 
    \\execute -m $executeCommandFile
else
    \\use different $defPassword(for example $defPassword2) and then execute
```

Think it's like try\catch but with plink used password

Answer (score 2):

`"Access is denied"` message appears in error stream. You can use the [Windows PowerShell redirection operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) e.g as follows:

```
$aux = . plink -batch -ssh $defUser@$srv -pw $defPassword -m $executeCommandFile *>&1
if ( $aux -match '^Access.*denied' ) {
    ### the specified string found: use different $defPassword
} else {
    ### success
    $aux              ### show plink results
}
```

Note that `2>&1` could suffice:

> - `*>&1` sends **all output types** (`*`) to the success output stream;
> - `2>&1` sends errors (`2`) and success output (`1`) to the success output stream.